# function $e^x$ as quotient of two polynomials

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function, rational-functions

Show that the function 
$e^x$
can not be expressed as a quotient of two polynomials.
A solution could be this:

Suppose $e^x=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ then $\quad \frac{e^x}{P(x)} = \frac{1}{Q(x)}$

We know that $e^x \quad$ tends to infinity faster than any power of $x$.
So if we do

$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^x}{P(x)} = \infty $ and

$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{Q(x)} = 0 $

we get a contradiction.

Do you think is it a good solution?

and .... could anyone suggest a better solution?

Comment: $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ would usually have some complex zeroes.

Comment: The argument is fine. You could also just say that a rational function is asymptotic to a power of $x$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you are allowed to assume, but if you are allowed to use standard differentiation rules - then a somewhat nice proof might be the following:

Assume, seeking a contradiction, that there exists polynomials $P$ and $Q$, such that $e^x = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$.

Then by differenting both sides, we get $e^x = \frac{P'(x) Q(x) - P(x)Q'(x)}{Q(x)^2}$ by the quotient rule.

Therefore $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = \frac{P'(x) Q(x) - P(x)Q'(x)}{Q(x)^2}$.

Rearranging both sides gives us $P(x) Q(x) = P'(x) Q(x) - P(x)Q'(x)$.

---

Now you have two polynomials on the left and the right. You should be able to reach a contradiction by considering the degree of the polynomials on each side.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a more formal reasoning, you can use the derivative. Let $n,m$ be the degrees of the polynomials $P_n(x),Q_m(x)$, respectively:
$$e^x=\frac{P_n(x)}{Q_m(x)}$$
Then, $e^x\,Q(x)=P(x)$ and you can differentiate both sides to obtain:
$$e^x\,Q_m(x)+e^x\,Q'_{m-1}(x)=P'_{n-1}(x)$$
so in the left-hand side you have a new polynomial **of the same degree** as $Q_m$, $R_m(x)=Q_m(x)+Q'_{m-1}(x)$ and:
$$e^x\,R_m(x)=P'_{n-1}(x)$$
Observe that the degree of the polynomial in the right-hand side decreases.

Repeating this process $n$ times, you finally obtain a polynomial $S_m(x)$ such that:
$$e^x\,S_m(x)=0$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: You need to argue that $S_m$ is nonzero. This can be done by noting that at each step the leading term of the polynomial on the left hand side does not change.

Comment: *Derive* in mathematics means “to obtain” (e.g., a formula); the verb that means “to take the derivative of” is *differentiate*, oddly enough.

Comment: @Aaron You are right. I tried to express that implicitly by indicating the degrees with subindices.

Comment: Brilliant proof!

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor You are right, just let me suggest that *derive* means "to obtain"... in English, not in Mathematics :) I translated literally from Spanish :(

Comment: @Miguel so you did! I had missed the significance of the subscripts in my initial reading.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor in most european countries with latin  language to derive is to take the derivative..so is it in Spain France and so on...

Comment: @Isham I understand completely—I speak Spanish fluently, just like Miguel. Nevertheless in English there is a distinction between whether one *derives* an equation or whether one *differentiates* both sides of it. This was a relevant teaching moment. When I first enrolled in calculus I made the same mistake.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor same for me I still make that mistake..

Answer (score 1):

For any two polynmials $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$, the limits$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$are identical in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$. But$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}e^x=+\infty\qquad\text{and}\qquad\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^x=0.$$

Comment: The limits are identical *if they exist*.

Comment: What you put is not entirely correct, take for example $P(x) = x$ and $Q(x) = 1$.

Comment: I've edited my answer; the limits can be $\pm\infty$.

Comment: Tanks to everybody, all posts are very useful.